# Algorithm that sorts a permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, permutation

I am stuck at this problem:

---

Given a permutation P of {0,1,2,...,n-1} 
(Here n = P . length)

Explain why the following algorithm sorts the permutation in increasing order and give a worst case scenario (pseudo-code)

```
PermutationSort(P)
    for i = 0 to P.length - 1
        while(P[i] != i)
            t = P[i]
            exchange P[i] with P[t]
```

(C++ code)

```
void PermutationSort(int P[], int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        while(P[i] != i)
        {
            int tmp;
            tmp = P[i];
            P[i] = P[tmp];
            P[tmp] = tmp;
        }
}
```

---

I am totally don't know why it sorts the permutation P.

I've sat on this problem all day and I'm still don't get **why** it sorts the permutation.

what "exchange P[i] with P[P[i]]" does and why we will ultimately get P[i] = i which will then terminate the inner loop?

Thanks for any hint or help.

Comment: A permutation with size N is (of course) `0,1,2,...,N-1,N`. Ie. if it is sorted, the array index `[i]` helds the integer value `i`. ...

Comment: Hint: Every permutation can be decomposed into disjoint [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation). Consider what your inner loop does to the cycle containing `i` and `P[i]`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks a lot for your hint. I've researched the Internet and read some papers and now I (almost) understand it. It is actually something like 'cycle' sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that, if you start at any arbitrary element *k*, and repeatedly apply the permutation *P* to obtain a chain like (*k* → *P*(*k*) → *P*(*P*(*k*)) → *P*(*P*(*P*(*k*))) → ...), you will (since the total number of elements in the permutation *P* is finite, and a permutation never maps two inputs to the same output) eventually end up back at *k*.  The [cycle](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) of elements (k →*P*(*k*) → *P*(*P*(*k*)) → ... → *k*) is called the [orbit](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(group_theory)) of *k* under *P*, and every element of the permutation belongs to exactly one such cycle.

Now, let's see what the inner loop of your algorithm does to the cycle containing the element *i*.

If *P*(*i* ) = *i*, i.e. if this element is already where it belongs, then the inner loop just does nothing and the outer loop moves on to the next element.  If *P*(*i* ) ≠ *i*, however, the inner loop sets *t* = *P*(*i* ), and then modifies the permutation *P* to swap *P*(*i* ) and *P*(*t* ).

After the swap, the new value of *P*(*t* ) is the old value of *P*(*i* ), i.e. *t*.  Thus, the element *t* is now correctly sorted, while *P*(*i* ) now contains the old value of *P*(*t* ) = *P*(*P*(*i* )), i.e. the (former) next element in the cycle.  If this is *i*, then there are no more elements left in the cycle, and the inner loop ends; otherwise, the cycle containing *i* has shrunk by one element, and the inner loop repeats.

Thus, at the end of the inner loop, all the elements that used to be part of the same cycle as *i* (including *i* itself) have been moved to their correct locations, and thus removed from the cycle, while the rest of the permutation has not been changed.

Since the outer loop iterates over every element in the permutation, it is also guaranteed to visit every cycle at least once.  Of course, we're modifying the permutation in the inner loop, but that's all right, since the inner loop can never create new cycles (of more than one element); it can only break up existing ones.

Thus, the first time each cycle in the original permutation gets visited by the outer loop, the inner loop sorts and breaks up that cycle; on subsequent visits to the same original cycle, that cycle has already been sorted, and so the inner loop simply does nothing.

This observation should also allow you to bound the number of times the inner loop can be executed, and thus to determine the time complexity of the algorithm.